# isoperimetric problems on Alexandrov spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, alexandrov-geometry

For an Alexandrov space M with curvature bounded from below,  the isoperimetric profile $v \to I_M(v)$ defined for every $v\in (0,V(M))$ (the volume of M might be infinite), is given by 
$$
 I_M(v)=inf\{A(\partial D): V(D)=v, D  \subset  \subset M\},
$$
where D varies over relatively compact open subset of M.

Then given any $v\in (0,V(M))$, is there a subset D with $A(\partial D)=I_M(v)$?

And are there any discription and regularity theorem for D and $\partial D$?

If we haven't results for general n, then what about the two-dimensional case?

Answer (score 1):

The existence follows from theory of currents the same way as for Riemannian manifolds.

As far as I know, there are no regularity results for $\partial D$.
But look at the proof of Levy--Gromov isoperimetric inequality in Alexandrov space [Theorem C in my "[Harmonic functions on Alexandrov spaces...](https://www-ams-org.ezaccess.libraries.psu.edu/journals/era/2003-09-17/S1079-6762-03-00120-3/)"] it does not use regularity.